# Connecting a visualization layer to a kafka streams / ksqlDB table?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I've been fiddling around with ksqlDB and it's really neat. Getting the data into Kafka, creating streams and even tables is working out nicely. I would now like to connect a visualization layer/BI tool to the data in the tables for creating a dashboard or some interactive BI report (e.g. Superset, Redash, etc).

Is there a way to connect a JDBC client directly to ksqlDB / Kafka Streams so it can query the tables in ksqlDB?
[This video](https://youtu.be/D5QMqapzX8o) kind of says I should use the REST API for hooking up an app to the results, but:

1. The REST API is proprietary, so how would I connect something like a BI tool to it without writing a custom connecter?
2. If I run ksqlDB in production/headless mode the REST API is not available anyway. (why??)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean proprietary?? And headless literally means there's nothing externally exposed. And JDBC isn't a streaming technology, so it wouldn't work

Comment: https://www.arcadiadata.com/product/streaming-visualizations/#instantKSQL

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the questions, answers in the same order: By proprietary I mean that standard visualization tools will not connect to it, even though it's exposing an SQL-based interface. In ksqlDB documentation, the "production" mode is the same as "headless" mode, while the "API is open" mode is advertised for "development" - It's unclear if that's a recommendation not to use the API in production, or just a inaccurate name for it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Tables in Kafka streams and ksqlDB are not streaming entities, they work just like normal tables, except they update. you can run on them what ksqlDB calls "pull queries", which are just like regular non-streaming SQL queries. I don't see any reason why JDBC would not be able to facilitate these "pull" queries.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the link to Arcadia. Hoping I will also be able to hook up to ksqlDB some common opensource BI tools.

Comment: By streaming I mean that the results won't update in your bi tools unless you schedule the query to rerun itself. I'm not sure the tools you listed support that. In any case, you can connect Presto or Hive to Kafka without even using ksql, then connect bi tools to those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect a JDBC client directly to ksqlDB / Kafka Streams so it can query the tables in ksqlDB?

There is a [community JDBC driver](https://github.com/mmolimar/ksql-jdbc-driver) for ksqlDB.

Bear in mind that *currently* ksqlDB is not intended for ad-hoc random access patterns. You may want to design your streams and tables carefully to optimise for the type of queries you're running.

Comment: Thanks Robin! Can you recommend a good way to instead replicate a ksql table into an SQL DB table? Create a stream of changes on the table and hook that stream up to the DB with the Kafka JDBC sink connector?

Comment: Yes - a table in ksqlDB is backed by a Kafka topic, so you can stream that to a target DB. Just make sure that the key is set correctly so that as values update in ksqlDB they update (not insert) in the target DB